# Running DOS in Linux Mint with WINE

Tags: linux, wine

I've tried installing WINE with WINEtricks, as I want to run a DOS window on a Linux Mint 64 bit system.  So far, I haven't been successful at doing this.  Has anyone been able to accomplish this task, and if so, what installation and setup tricks did you use?

Answer (score 3):

On Linux Mint, installing Wine with

```
sudo apt install wine
```

will then allow you to run Wine’s implementation of the Windows command-line interpreter by running

```
wine cmd
```

If you’re really looking for DOS, the simplest option is to install DOSBox:

```
sudo apt install dosbox
```

Running

```
dosbox
```

will then open a DOS emulator.

Wine can automatically use DOSBox to run DOS binaries.

You’ll also find DOSEMU (the `dosemu` package) but it’s possibly a little harder to set up.